# How to calculate with decimal-numbers? (C#)

Tags: c#, decimal

I am getting a Sytem.FormatException error when trying to calculate using decimals. It works for numbers that are not decimal.
What do I need to add / change in order for it to work with decimal numbers?

This is my code:

```
namespace Nikotin_Rechner

    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void buttonCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int val1 = Int32.Parse(AngabeGesamt.Text);
                int val2 = Int32.Parse(AngabeStärke.Text);

                int result = val1 / 20 * val2;
                labelBase.Text = result.ToString();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do floating point stuff on ints? Did you read the definition of integer?

Comment: `double val1 = double.Parse(AngabeGesamt.Text);... double result = val1/val2;`

Comment: `Int32.Parse` should be changed to `decimal.Parse` or `double.Parse` & all `int`s replaced by `decimal` or `double`.

Comment: Use `M` suffix to define `decimal` constant. E.g. `20M` or `3.14M`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want *floating point* values you have to change type `int` to, say, `double` (`float`, `decimal`):

```
private void buttonCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double val1 = double.Parse(AngabeGesamt.Text);
    double val2 = double.Parse(AngabeStärke.Text);

    double result = val1 / 20 * val2;
    labelBase.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a different type instead of `int`, I'd recommend `double` in your case. Something like this:

```
private void buttonCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    double val1 = double.Parse(AngabeGesamt.Text);
    double val2 = double.Parse(AngabeStärke.Text);

    double result = val1 / 20 * val2;
    labelBase.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Please see the official C# documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: Double is working fine as of now. Thanks for providing me this link I will look into it!

Comment: Good to hear it, if you need anything else just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

this code can do that

```
        decimal val1 = decimal.Parse("9");
        decimal val2 = decimal.Parse("7");

        decimal result = (val1 / 20 )* val2;
        Console.Write(result);
```

result is `3.15`